# location values change every few seconds - navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition

Tags: html, google-maps, geolocation

I store the users current location in a cookie, and in the meantime, I upload the map, while I get the new current location.

if the location didn't change I leave it as it is, if not, I reload the map with the new location.

the problem is that the location is changing by very small numbers every few seconds. Even if you don't even move (I'm with a PC, so not moving at all).

```
if(navigator.geolocation){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
location=new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
}
}
```

Is there a way to get a static geolocation?

thanks
Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You probably don't want to actually create a whole new map every time you get the position, do you? Maybe you're looking for the panTo function in the google maps API?
2. If you're polling for the location, you're better off using navigator.geolocation.watchPosition() which only calls back when the position has changed.

Comment: Wow Josh, the watchPosition works so good !!! I didn't know it existed ;o) and you really got me thinking about my entire website, with your first point, I was reloading the map in every click. Thanks a lot.